# Django - Serving Media ValueError

Tags: django, media, static-files

I'm trying to serve user uploaded media files in my dev environment.

```
#settings.py
#[...]
import os
SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = (os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'media/'))
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(SITE_ROOT, 'static/'),
)
#[...]

#url.py
urlpatterns = patterns('',
  #[...]
  url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:], 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root', settings.MEDIA_ROOT}
  ),
  url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.STATIC_URL[1:], 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root', settings.STATIC_ROOT}
  ),
)
```

Trying to access an uploded file like http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/videos/julian_06.flv, I get

> ValueError at /media/videos/julian_06.flv
>
> dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 40; 2 is required

Comment: are other files being served correctly? Like pictures or css?

Comment: Yes they are. No problem with static files

Comment: that is peculiar. When I replicated the code nothing was serving for me. Could it be possible that the other files were cached somehow? Glad we fixed it with the typo though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend trying to follow the docs for [static hosting in development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#static-file-development-view)

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += patterns('django.contrib.staticfiles.views',
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'serve'),
)
```

**EDIT:**

Your dictionary should have a **`:`** not **`,`** between the `'document_root'` and `settings.MEDIA_ROOT`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % settings.MEDIA_URL[1:], 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

Comment: This was indeed the `:` instead of `,` I'm wondering how it was working for the static files... And by the way, why can we put `'serve'` instead of `'django.views.static.serve'` ?

Comment: if you look at the first method i put, it calls `django.contrib.staticfiles.views` right after the `patterns(`. So every regex in that pattern group will call from that view. It can be a good way to add DRYness to your urls if you call from the same view multiple times [Docs: The View Prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/urls/#the-view-prefix)